# APNS Certificate production

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

Did I miss something?

I've created some push notifications in Xamarin.iOS and it works perfectly with the Development certificate.
Then I created a Production certificate and it doesn't work.

Does APNS work differently in Production?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work". How do you test that? Please post the efforts you have done.

Comment: I tested it on my iPhone. It works when it is set to development - I receive push notification. When I set it to production, I do not receive it.

Comment: You should use ad hoc certification to test production push notification.

Comment: I tested my app on production with TestFlight. So, I do have a Ad Hoc Certification.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to doublecheck. Make sure that:

1. You're using an *App Store and Ad Hoc* certificate to sign your app.
2. You're using an *Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)* certificate on the server side
3. The `aps-environment` value in your `info.plist` is set to `production`

Comment: 1. My app is running on TestFlight. I suppose it is fine.
2. On server side? I've just checked Azure Notification Hub and it is set to sandbox instead of production. That may be the issue?
3. I have nothing called aps-environment inside info.plist. Should I add this value?